# How can I center the cursor vertically after jumping to a line?

Tags: cursor-movement

I often use `:line` to jump to a line number. How can I automatically center that line vertically after jumping? Essentially the same as running `:150zz`.

Comment: Wait. This doesn't happen for you automatically? Every time I enter a line number at the command line the jumped-to line is vertically centered. Oh wait...maybe you mean when the jump is small (i.e. the visible lines don't change). Is that right?

Comment: No, it never happens. If the page has to scroll then the cursor is at the very extremes of the page (either top or bottom).

Comment: You can probably get close with `set scrolloff=998`, but that has other effects (I prefer more like 5 or so).

Comment: How strange. Even with `-u NONE` or `--clean` I get cursor line centered as long as the jump is to a line not currently on screen. You might try that too (`vim --clean filename`)...it may indicate that your current config has something preventing the behavior I describe.

Comment: @BLayer it works for me the way you describe only for help buffers. All others are as OP describes.

Comment: @BLayer I was wrong -- it depends on the "how far" one jumps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "centering" depends on the length of the jump with the rough ratio `(window lines / jump lenght) == 0.625`:

If

- you have 45 window lines and you jump more than 69 lines or
- you have 22 window lines and you jump more than 33 lines or
- you have 15 window lines and you jump more than 23 lines

then cursor would be centered in window, otherwise not.

I am not sure if there is an option that you can use to change "jump center size", but `set scrolloff=999` makes your cursor almost always be centered.

Another option would be to map command line `<CR>` to `zz` after a range:

```
cnoremap <expr> <CR> (getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() =~ '\d\+') ? "<CR>zz" : "<CR>"
```

Comment: Hmm. Made sense to me when I thought it was determined by the target line being visible or not. This ratio driven formula...not so much. Wonder what the rationale is behind it.

Comment: @Maxim Kim Shouldn't part of the comparison in your answer be `getcmdline() =~ '^\d\+$'`, i.e. with the `^` and `$` anchors in the regexp, instead of just `getcmdline() =~ '\d\+'`?